# How can I limit the times a script runs from within tmux?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, zsh, tmux

I have a script which pings a website and tells me how much time I've worked in the week. I want that to be in the status bar in my `tmux.conf`, but I'm having the issue of the script running about once every second, which obviously floods the network. Is there a way to limit this from happening without getting the tmux `<"cmd" not ready>` text show up?

Currently in my `tmux.conf`, I have this command.

`set -g status-right '#[fg=colour6,bold]#(watch -n 60 zsh 
                 ~/directory/src/directory/scripts/time.zsh)'`

But when it runs, I get

`<'watch -n 60 zsh ~/directory/src/directory/scripts/time.zsh' not ready>`

Is there a way to maybe preserve the last time it ran and suppress this message? Thank you.

Comment: can you have a cron job do the web stuff at some interval (a few times per hour or whatever) and write that to a local file, then have tmux just read from that file?

Comment: You can set how often shell commands in the status line are run with `status-interval` which by default seems to be 15 seconds, so perhaps change this to 60 and remove the `watch` part.

Comment: @thrig, that'd probably work actually. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: @meuh I tried that, but the problem with that is it still updates whenever switching windows/panes. Not a huge deal and still a solid solution, but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your script time.zsh to cache the result in one file , and each your script is call it will test the age of the file .

```
CACHE_OUTPUT=/tmp/resul-cache.txt
AGE_TO_CACHE=10
if [ $(( $( stat --format=%Y $CACHE_OUTPUT ) + $AGE_TO_CACHE )) -gt $( date +%s ) && echo too old ) ] ;
then
    cat $CACHE_OUTPUT
    exit 0
fi
(
    # where you fetch 
    # ...
    # 
) > $CACHE_OUTPUT
```